# Is there a lighter alternative to puppeteer for simulated clicking?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, node.js, simulation, scraping

I'm writing an application that navigates to a website, clicks a button on the website (which updates it) and then extracts information from the website. The application requires a headless browser, but I'm **only using it for clicking a button**. I'm currently using puppeteer because it seems highly renowned in the webscraping community, but I've noticed that it is somewhat slow and extremely large (difficult to push to github). Is there a lighter alternative to puppeteer that would accomplish my goal?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a software recommendation, hence as comment: check what the action of that button is. Usually it's some POST or GET. Then just perform that, no clicking needed. Of course things look a bit different if the click just triggers some AJAX action…

Comment: @Izzy the button accesses an external database to which I do not have access in order to update all of the information on the page.

Comment: I didn't mean what happens when you press it, but rather what action/call is triggered (like the FORM target). It must trigger either a post/get or at least some AJAX call. If you can find out which that is, you could perform that directly.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry I'm so new at this... How do I do that? I inspected the page and tracked down the onclick function call and it is: onclick="$.OP.GG.summoner.renewBtn.start(this, '80749755');"  Is there something else that I should be looking for?

Comment: Now you'd need to locate the JQuery function called. I'm not really familiar with that (JQuery), and it's OT here anyway, sorry. I was rather expecting it would be a "simple form", not a button with JS events.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyJD, re "*requires a headless*"; Why not use a script on a headful browser?